# Current calculation of three-phase system with "extra" resistors

Tags: ac, three-phase

[image: phase diagram]

I know you usually say that I should solve it a little bit and then ask for help, but in this question unfortunately I don't know where to start.

This is a question about a three-phase circuit with extra resistors. I should find the absolute value of Ia as well as a phase diagram.

Comment: Convert 'resistances in delta' to 'resistances in star'.

Answer (score 2):

If 3R is what you mean "extra resistors", then I am telling you that those are not "extra" at all. Those are representations of impedance per phase of your load connected in delta. To give you an example, we may say that those 3R represents three individual windings of your 3-phase delta-connected motor load.

To solve for \$I_a\$, I recommend to follow these steps:

- Step 1: If you were given a phase voltage from your wye-connected source, **calculate the respective line voltages first.**
- Step 2: **Solve for phase currents** (this is where you will use that "extra resistor" given)
- Step 3: You already have your phase current so now **calculate the respective line currents.**

Voila! You have solved you \$I_a\$ together with \$I_b\$ and \$I_c\$.